# Гистограмма частот R

Tags: r, статистика

У меня есть задание, в ексель создать набор данных из 20 целых чисел от 1 до 12. Нужно копировать их в R и сохранить в переменной S. Как мне создать гистогрмму частот и гистограмму относительных частот, если у меня S получается в data.frame, а для гистограммы нужен вектор или я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 1):

Вы всегда можете обратиться к вектору (колонке датафрейма в Вашем случае) при помощи
df$S, где df-название Вашего датафрейма.